# I want to get the system keyEvent from java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a program that will get all the system keyEvents when ever it is pressed (it may be on web browser or any key press for any other program ).Is there any function to retrive which key is pressed to do this job. Thanx in advance.

Comment: what kind of program are you going to build? I hope it isn't a keylogger ...

Comment: Get system key events with un-modified core Java? Answer: you don't. Choose the right tool for the job, and since Java was built to be OS-agnostic, it is of necessity removed from the OS and has limited abilities on its own to interact as closely with the OS as something like this would require. So you'll have to create your key snooper and listen to your wife's chatting using some other programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no such function in JDK. May be you can use Java Native Interface?

Comment: should be a comment, perhaps?